# Choosing Java Restful framework for heavily loaded server

Tags: java, rest, load

I'm trying to figure out what Java Restful framework is the best suitable fom heavily loaded identity manager server.
Did someone run load tests for Restful frameworks and is willing to share the conclusion?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Great question!  You'll probably find that the framework choice is not your primary determiner of performance/scalability.  We've used [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/), based on a very strong recommendation from a former colleague who used it to develop Overstock.com (a very large e-commerce site).  It has good performance, and it works fine for Overstock.com.  But we didn't do any head to head comparisons.

One of the big drivers for REST is its scalability, a quality of a distributed system whereby you can accomodate an increase in usage with a proportional increase in system size and cost.  Caching is a key technique to achieve scalability.  So if you allow your representations to be cached, much of the load is actually not borne by the identity management system but by web caches downstream.  This is independent of the REST framework.

Your backend database technology is likely another primary factor in system performance and scaling.  Tuning the database system and optimizing queries may pay off here.  Also consider whether adding a database cache layer makes sense (eg, OpenSymphony).

We found that serialization costs were quite significant for us.  Overall request rates were best if we used the Kryo or Smile binary serializations.  If you need a textual serialization, we found that the Jackson JSON serializer was much faster then the XStream XML serializer, doubling the overall request rate.  This might be an area to consider.

So if you haven't done so, examine your system from a scaling perspective.  See http://www.highscalability.com, Richardson and Ruby's Restful Web Services (O'Reilly), Cal Henderson's [Building Scalable Web Sites](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596102357), and Theo Schlossnagle's [Scalable Internet Architectures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232699X) for a start.